# Trying to draw multiple instances of a sprite object in pygame, and the first one draws correctly but the next show the background only

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a diagonal row of hexagons, but when I try to draw them only the first one works. [Here's a screenshot of the pygame window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3DZu.png) There should be hexagons in every black box.

Here is the code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit

pygame.init()

screen_width = 800
screen_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height), 0, 32)

class Hex(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, s_len, op):
        super().__init__()
        x, y = op
        root3 = 1.73205080
        self.color = (125,200,24)
        self.op = op
        self.s_len = s_len
        self.points = [(x + (.5 * s_len), y),
                       (x + (1.5 * s_len), y),
                       (x + (2 * s_len), y + ((root3 / 2) * s_len)),
                       (x + (1.5 * s_len), y + (root3 * s_len)),
                       (x + (.5 * s_len), y + (root3 * s_len)),
                       (x, y + (root3 / 2) * s_len)]

        self.image = pygame.Surface([2 * s_len, root3 * s_len])
        self.image.fill((0,0,0))
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.image, self.color, self.points)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)


hex_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(7):
    hex_group.add(Hex(50, (i * 75, i * 86)))


while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()

    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    hex_group.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
```

I think the issue must have something to do with the self.image creation in my Hex class constructor, but no clue how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing the polygon on the image not on the screen. The top left of `self.image` is (0, 0):

```py
self.points = [(.5 * s_len, 0),
               (1.5 * s_len, 0),
               (2 * s_len, (root3 / 2) * s_len),
               (1.5 * s_len, root3 * s_len),
               (.5 * s_len, root3 * s_len),
               (0, (root3 / 2) * s_len)]
```

---

Complete exemple:

[image]

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit

pygame.init()

screen_width = 800
screen_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height), 0, 32)

class Hex(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, s_len, op):
        super().__init__()
        x, y = op
        root3 = 1.73205080
        self.color = (125,200,24)
        self.op = op
        self.s_len = s_len
        self.points = [(.5 * s_len, 0),
               (1.5 * s_len, 0),
               (2 * s_len, (root3 / 2) * s_len),
               (1.5 * s_len, root3 * s_len),
               (.5 * s_len, root3 * s_len),
               (0, (root3 / 2) * s_len)]

        self.image = pygame.Surface([2 * s_len, root3 * s_len])
        self.image.fill((0,0,0))
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.image, self.color, self.points)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)


hex_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(7):
    hex_group.add(Hex(50, (i * 75, i * 86)))


while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()

    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    hex_group.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
```